# Create SQL Column Counting Frequency of Value in other column

Tags: postgresql

I have the first three columns in SQL. I want to create the 4th column called *Count* which counts the number of times each unique name appears in the *Name* column. I want my results to appears like the dataset below, so I don't want to do a COUNT and GROUP BY.

What is the best way to achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try to use `COUNT` window function

```
SELECT *,COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY year,month) count
FROM T 
ORDER BY year,month
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a114177a38d17e4d07169c36982aaf64)